# создать сложный запрос mysql wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Не могли бы вы помочь мне переделать сложный запрос к базе данных с подсчетом постов? Ситуация такая. Есть каталог объявлений на wordpress и поиск(фильтрация). На главной странице отображается список всех категорий с кол-вом объявлений в каждой из них. Человек вводит в форму Город, Тип объявления и ключевое слово. Он может вводить все параметры или только одно из них. Скрипт должен выводить кол-во объявлений в каждой категории. Мой вариант считает, но это очень долго. Сейчас объявлений не так много. Если будет больше это вообще повесит сайт...

```
<?php

 $querystr = "SELECT *  FROM $wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = ".$category->cat_ID." AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

$count=0;
foreach($pageposts as $post) { 
setup_postdata($post); 

$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:S');

$validity = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'valid_until', true);

$city = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_location', true);

$action = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_action', true);


$cities = explode("|", $city);

$session_city = $_SESSION["session_city"];

if($_SESSION["session_city"] and !$_SESSION["session_action"] or $_SESSION["session_action"]=='All') {
    if($validity >= $today and in_array($session_city, $cities)) { $count++;}
}

if($_SESSION["session_action"] and !$_SESSION["session_city"] or $_SESSION["session_city"]=='All') {
    if($validity >= $today and $action == $_SESSION["session_action"]) { $count++;}
}

if($_SESSION["session_action"] and $_SESSION["session_city"]) {
    if($validity >= $today and $action == $_SESSION["session_action"] and in_array($session_city, $cities)) { $count++;}
}

if(!isset($_SESSION["session_city"]) and !isset($_SESSION["session_action"])) {
    if($validity >= $today) { $count++;}
}


}

echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: Вообще все нужно считать одним запросом, а не в php. Вы бы хоть сказали из каких таблиц поля которые вы анализируете, вот те valid_until, post_location, post_action. Еще бы понять все ли таблицы, которые в запросе клеятся там действительно нужны

Comment: у меня мозгов не хватило создать в mysql запрос, потому пришлось с php счиать. valid_until, post_location, post_action все хранится в post_meta wordpress таблице. потому и не получается из нее доставть данные простыми запросами... $timestamp извиняюсь, там вообще не нужен. удалил :)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял логику здесь происходящего, то вам надо ваш запрос дополнить дополнительными условиями, в зависимости от фильтров. Судя по всему вы всегда берете только записи у которых valid_until больше текущей даты, тогда его так же надо добавить в запрос. Должно получится примерно так:

```
$querystr = "SELECT count(1) as cnt FROM $wpdb->posts
   INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
   INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
   WHERE (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = ".$category->cat_ID." AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
     AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
     AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')

     AND valid_until >= now()
   ";

if($_SESSION["session_city"]) {
 $querystr.=" AND concat('|',post_location,'|') like '%|".$_SESSION["session_city"]."|%'";
} // SQL: AND concat('|',post_location,'|') like '%|Москва|%'

if($_SESSION["session_action"] && $_SESSION["session_action"]!='All') {
 $querystr.=" AND post_action='".$_SESSION["session_action"]."'";
} // SQL: AND post_action='xyz'

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
$count=$pageposts[0]['cnt']; // Проверьте как он реально выглядит, это предположение, что оно там
```

Запрос вернет единственное число - требуемое количество. Как вы понимаете, все это написано на глаз, без проверок. Надо собрать запрос руками с подходящими параметрами и проверить.

**Внимание**: это примерный код, к нему *необходимо* добавить проверку переменных из `$_SESSION` на корректность, перед подстановкой в текст запроса. Как минимум они не должны содержать в себе апострофов (`'`), что бы не сломать запрос и не обеспечить возможности для SQL-инъекций